# Xcode set subproject scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, build, frameworks, scheme

I have project with app target and configurations R1, R2, D1 and D2. The project contains subproject with framework target which have configurations Debug and Release.

I want build frameworks configuration Debug for app configurations D1 and D2 and frameworks configuration Release for app configurations R1 and R2.

How set this configuration into Xcode? I do not want configurations R1, R2, D1 and D2 in framework. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you have separate schemes R1, R2, D1, and D2 or these are configurations duplicated form default Debug and Release configurations?

Comment: Each scheme have different configuration.

Comment: But you have mentioned all of your items (Debug, Release, D1, D2, R1, and R2) as schemes.. where as Debug and Release are typically the configurations for every scheme.

Comment: I updated the question. Everything is configuration.